# disable and enable mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

can someone help me with this ? I have a mouseenter and mouseleave effect, and want to disable it when click on other div.. 
this is my code

```
$('.offer-content').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).find('.offer-desc').show()
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
})
$(".st_sharethis").click(function(){
        $flex(".offer-content").off('mouseleave');
    });
```

what i want to happen is to enable the mouseenter and mouseleave again when i close the ".st_sharethis" class

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle with the required behavior. From your question it looks like you want to toggle the event behavior on the .st_sharethis click. Below code is working as expected.

Click on toggle event button and behavior with toggle with every click.

**Fiddle link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hPAjF/

**Updated version with better css:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hPAjF/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="offer-content"><div class="offer-desc"></div></div>

<div class="st_sharethis">Toggle events</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.offer-content{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#900;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.offer-desc{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#090;
    display:none;
}

.st_sharethis{

    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#009;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.offer-content').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).find('.offer-desc').show()
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
})
var mouseLeave = 0;
$(".st_sharethis").click(function(){
    if(mouseLeave==0)  
    {
        $(".offer-content").off('mouseleave');
        mouseLeave=1;
    }
    else
    {     $('.offer-content').on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
});
     mouseLeave = 1;
    }

    });
```

**In your website i have added following code from console and it has given the behavior you want.**

```
jQuery(".stCloseNew2").click(function(){

jQuery('.offer-content').on('mouseleave', function(){
   jQuery(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
});
});
```

Comment: actually the st_sharethis is a popup button, this is the site im currently working on http://tigerbills.co.uk/offers/

Comment: i want to enable the hover effect again once i close the share this button

Comment: You can add code $('.offer-content').on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
}); on the event you want to bring the events back again

Comment: I have added the behaviour on the toggle button clicking, i.e. once you click the button the mouse leave goes away. If you click that again mouse leave gets active. You can achieve this by keeping the current state of the event in a variable and then removing and adding the event from various other events.

Comment: When you are closing the popup just add the event back there and it will start working.!

Comment: I have tried adding the following code from the console of your website and it has given the required behavior:jQuery(".stCloseNew2").click(function(){

jQuery('.offer-content').on('mouseleave', function(){
   jQuery(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
});
});

Comment: try hovering to lunch offer, it will have hover effect and the share button will appear, when i click on share pop up div will appear, and when i close the popup the hover is not working anymore..

Comment: Try adding the code i added in the answer at the last , i hope this will work for you this time.

Comment: hi ! it works well on console.. and thank you for that, but weird thing is it doesn't work when i put it in under my code.. any idea why?

Comment: May be the location of putting this code is not correct try adding this code on $(window).on('load',function(){//add code here});

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the $flex to $

Below code will work for you:

```
$('.offer-content').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).find('.offer-desc').show()
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('.offer-desc').hide()
});
$(".st_sharethis").click(function(){
    $(".offer-content").off('mouseleave');
});
```

You can also test it : http://jsfiddle.net/Qz2Rk/

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.. but i want to get back the hover effect once i click again the .st_sharethis div..